# what is the Two-Block Haicut called in Chinese(Mandarin)?

Tags: translation, word, simplified-characters, word-requests

does anyone know what is the Chinese name for the **Two-Block Haircut**? I heard it can also be called the **Dandy Two-Block haircut**.

It is the one that is popularized by Korea and is shown in many Korean idols.

I would like to know the name for better describing it to my barber since my haircut is always inconsistent when I try to describe it.

Comment: Why not take a picture to show your barber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**二分区发型** or **二分区式发型**

[百度经验](https://jingyan.baidu.com/article/17bd8e52f905d585ab2bb80f.html)

> 男士二分区式发型越来越热，不仅清爽有个性，而且酷感十足，并且能让成为人们的焦点又能展现你的个性风格，更能吸引不少MM的目光呢！今天小编又为大家精选了最新6款男士二分区式发型。看看哪款适合你

---

An alternate: **两块式发型**

Answer (score 1):

On 小红书, I notice there are many types of two-block haircuts. Or the "mushroom hair".

These are all on a basis of the the name "**盖发**" (bowl cut), combining the characters for cover (盖) and hair (发）。

When communicating with a barber, it is best to add the noun "碎" (fragmented) when trying to describe its fragmented/layered texture. Or else a inexperienced barber may give you a very vulgar haircut. （兄弟，你也不想要太土的发型吧。 +w+)。

Key terms:

- 盖发 (Bowl cut)
- 剪碎 (literally means to cut chop it; referring the action of texturing)
- 层次感 (To have a layered feel)
- 碎盖 (Fringed Bowl cut)
- 质地 (Texture)... *Usually you never use this one through.*

Example sentence:
If your hair is straight:

- “你好，我今天想要理个**盖发**。。。最好**剪碎一点**。给它点**层次感**！不过刘海不要打薄！”
- ("Hello, I would like a bowl cut today... Please layer it! I want it to have a a nice layered texture!")

If your hair is a bit wavy or curly and doesn't go well with too much layers. Like for me, if the root (发根) or my hair or the ends (发尾) of my hair is too thin, it'll curl up. However, to avoid looking too vulgar, it is still best to thin at the middle for a bit, but not the bang！ （在中间打薄一点）. QwQ:

- "你好，我今天想要理个盖发。不要打太薄。我头发有点自然卷，会卷起来的！不过还是剪出个层次感。。。比如在中间打薄是可以的。"
- (Hello, I would like a bowl cut today. However, don't thin it out too much. My hair is a bit curly. It'll curl up！ But it's okay to give it some layers, like maybe thinning at the middle。)

---

Here are some variation types of bowl cut:
中分盖发 - Center Parted Bowl Cut

微分碎盖 - Slightly Parted Bowl Cut (BEST FOR THOSE THAT LIKES THEIR HAIR THICK)

碎盖刘垓 - Fringed Bowl Cut

微平碎盖 - Slightly Flat Fringed Bowl Cut

逗号刘海  - Comma Bangs

日式碎盖 - Japanese-style Fringed Bowl Cut

韩式碎盖 - Korean-style Fringed Bowl Cut

Additionally note that parted hair can also be called Curtained hair (窗帘式发型).